# Firebase OTP verification without signin in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

How to send an OTP through firebase and verify it without signing in?
Like normally, the firebase receives the otp and calls the signInWithPhoneNumber and sign's in to firebase. 
I don't want to sign in with that method. 
I just want to get the otp from firebase and verify if It is correct or not and perform my custom operation if it is correct.
Thanks in advance.
Alternatively, I need to use otp for my custom verification. Suggest me any other methods to verify if the otp is correct or not(SMS).

Comment: have a look [at this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)

Comment: as per documentation it seems like we cannot verify number without signing in. one thing you can do sign out user from firebase auth just after signing in

Answer (score 0):

After receiving OTP call verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String mverificationId, (Received OTP))

```
private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {
                if(code.equals(mResendToken)&&verificationId.equals(mVerificationId)){
            ............
            ............
            //do your work
            ............
            ............
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please provide correct OTP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) helps to improve the quality of your response. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.